# How to determine if the disk performance is enough

Tags: performance, storage

I'm trying to make a storage performance test technique for recording from video sources. Let's say, I know, that my HDD on Ubuntu can handle about 130 parallel sequential writes of video ~3000kB/sec each. And I have "unknown" storage that I want to measure some metrics and determine what count of video sources it can handle. For now I'm using *iostat* to get some metrics (iops, latency, speed) on my HDD with 130 sources load. Tried to use *fio*, but I don't know how to set particular write speed (~3000kB * 130 threads).
So, the question is - How to simulate needed 'incoming to write' bandwidth? What metrics I should notice to determine that storage performance is enough?
Thanks

Comment: You are asking a hardware question. this is off topic on this site. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @David I think I disagree. OP is asking for tools to measure and generate I/O throughput, not asking about hardware per se. Likewise, if you wanted to measure your network speed, it wouldn't be about the router itself.

Comment: Yep, I need some point from which I can start. May be I should write 130, 200, 300 sources to disk and record IOs by blktrace and then replay them by fio or btreplay on another system with unknown storage and pay attention to some(what?) values of iostat?

Comment: Investigate/google "`bonnie++`" it's a disk performance measurement tool.

Comment: Found near solution is using 'rate' parameter of fio util. I configured rate with several threads, but iostat shows strange behavior - in some time intervals disk write are zero bytes, on another intervals write bandwith is higher then 'rate' * 'num_jobs'. Maybe there are some another parameters that can affect this behaviour to change disk load more constant